# Find $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x \sin {\frac{\pi}{x}})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Find $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x \sin {\frac{\pi}{x}})$

I know that the solution is $1$, but that’s what I got:

$\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x \sin {\frac{\pi}{x}})= \lim_{x \to 0} 1+ \lim_{x \to 0} x \sin {\frac{\pi}{x}}$
$=1+\pi \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin {\frac{\pi}{x}} }{\frac {\pi}{x}}$
$=1+\pi (1)$
$=1+\pi $

Can you tell me where was I mistaken?

EDIT:

$|\sin \frac{\pi}{x}| \leq 1$

$-1\leq \sin \frac{\pi}{x} \leq 1$

$-|x| \leq |x \sin \frac{\pi}{x}| \leq |x|$

So $  \lim_{x \to 0} x \sin {\frac{\pi}{x}} =0$

And therefore $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x \sin {\frac{\pi}{x}})=1$

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\sin$ is bounded. Also, you are computing the limit of $\sin w /w$ at infinity and not at $0$.

Comment: The limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of $\frac{\sin(\pi/x)}{\pi/x}$ does not equal $1$.

Comment: @Joe It't not just not equal $1$, it does not exist.

Comment: @CiaPan I think it does exist. Consider $\frac{x\sin(\pi/x)}{\pi}$. The numerator goes to $0$, since $\sin(\pi/x)$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$ and $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Whoops! :( You're right!

Comment: The lower bound $-|x|$ is unnecessary since the absolute value is non-negative.

Comment: @Gary Right! Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final limit is just 1. Due to Sandwich theorem:
$$-x \le x \sin (\pi/x) \le x \implies \lim_{x \to 0} x \sin(\pi/x) =0$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For real $x,$  $$\left|\sin\dfrac{\pi}x\right|\le1$$

$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}x\cdot \sin\dfrac{\pi}x=?$$

Answer (score 1):

To compute
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi/x)}{\pi/x} \, ,
$$
presumably you wrote that $\sin(\pi/x) \approx \pi/x$ and proceeded from there. However, this is not valid. Can you see why?

Comment: Thanks, that’s right. At $x=1$, for example, we have $0=\sin \pi \neq =\frac{\pi}{1}=\pi$?

Comment: @Dima The approximation $\sin w \approx w$ is valid when $w\to 0$. However as $x\to 0$, $\pi/x$ tends to $\infty$ and not to $0$.